# Пропуск файлов, которые не получается подсчитать

Tags: c#

Писал программу для копирования некоторых файлов, в ней есть подсчёт файлов во всей папке. Но подсчёт в скрытой системной папке, к которой нет доступа. Ошибка возникает в коде с подсчётом, можно ли как-то пропускать такие папки?

Вот та строчка кода, которая вызывает ошибку:

```
            //узнаём сколько файлов в папке
            int i = 0;
            
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(SourcePath);
            if (directoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                // ищем во всех папках                
                i = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
 
            }
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(SourcePath2);
            if (directoryInfo2.Exists)
            {
                // ищем во всех папках                
                i += directoryInfo2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
 
            }
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
            progressBar1.Maximum = i;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3612081/11837368 , можете ещё флаг `FileAttributes.System` проверять

Comment: Это для перегрузки `GetFiles` с `EnumerationOptions`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.